# Do page views on Closed questions count towards MW3 vs Skyrim?

Tags: support, site-promotion

Do page views on Closed questions count towards the competition between Q&A Site views MW3 vs. Skyrim?

Because I think they shouldn't.

Comment: My inclination would be to believe that they do not, but I've asked internally to check on this.

Comment: Well, I have this nice, answered, +6, **closed** 308-view (as of right now) Skyrim question (which is more than most other Skyrim questions have). Would be kinda sad if it didn't count. :D

Comment: @MartinSojka That definitely won't count, since it was asked a week before the release date.

Comment: @lunboks: "asked Nov 4", which is within 7 days of the release - unless you're thinking of some other question. Alas, woe is me, closed question don't count according to David. :D

Comment: @MartinSojka Yes, that one. Exactly 7 days too early to count. Also closed, I guess.

Comment: @Martin It's 7 days *after* release, not 7 days from.

Answer (score 6):

Per [the official rules](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/rules):

> Views on deleted or closed questions, or views that are recorded
>   before or after the 7-day period of each contest will not be counted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the rules. Must read before post :)